# Disable HTTPS for particular ZF1 module

Tags: php, apache, http, zend-framework, https

**Requirement**:
I've an existing site in ZF1, running on HTTPS. Following is setting in virtual host for that:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/sitename/public

...

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/server.pem
```

Now problem is, we want to add few pages (a whole module) using HTTP, not HTTPS. For example, we need following URLS

**Existing**

```
https://www.sitename.com/module1/...
https://www.sitename.com/module2/...
https://www.sitename.com/module3/...
```

**new required**

```
http://www.sitename.com/modulex/...
```

In ZF1, since we have single entry point (public/index.php), I was wondering if it is possible.

In ZF1, is it possible to run few modules through HTTPS and few other with HTTP? If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: No answer till now. I guess it mean it is not possible. However can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a previous Zend Framework application I created, I had to use HTTPS when configured, so I did it like following:

```
// Force users on HTTPS if configured
if ( $config->httpsOnly && empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
    $httpsUrl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $httpsUrl");
}
```

And it worked very well, I guess in your case, you can do it in the `init` function of your module controllers (or if you are using an abstraction you can use it in the abstract controller), I would suggest something like:

```
// Force users on HTTP, if using HTTPS
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
    $httpUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $httpUrl");
}
```

I hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks Abu, I accepted that answer as finally we are using this solution although with some changes. We put the code mentioned in this solution in a plugin and updated virtual hosts a bit. That solution is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance which caused bounty to go to another answer. But we had to go through all three answer to find which fits in our project best. If possible, I'd have given bounty to this answer.

Comment: Its okay, knowing that my answer helped you is worth more than any S.O bounty, thanks for accepting

Answer (score 2):

If you want create `moduleX` is accessed by HTTP-requests only, try this:

```
class ModuleX_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
   public function _initModule(){
       $this->_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a regular apache question, you can solve this with some Rewrite rules.
First make your vhost config serve both :443 (https) and :80 (http) with same DocumentRoot.

Then use a RewriteRule like this (either in the vhost conf or in htaccess of your DocumentRoot):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/modulex
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/modulex
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically first rule says if attempting to hit modulex at https, redirect to http.
Second rule says if attempting to hit anything other than modulex at http, redirect to https.